# End-of-life for Web Spell Checker (WSC) dialog plugin for CKEditor 4

Tags: ckeditor

A client of ours recently brought to our attention that the spell checker functionality that’s partnered with CKEditor 4 is coming to its end of life for the free version by the end of June 2021.

https://webspellchecker.com/blog/2020/12/02/end-of-life-for-spell-checker-dialog-plugin-for-ckeditor-4/

[image]

It’s a functionality they wish to continue to use, what alternatives/options are available?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that the client accepted so thought I’d share –

Enable the browser spell check functionality.

Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences > Configure CKEditor

By default, native browser spell check functionality is disabled in the editor. Use the config.disableNativeSpellChecker configuration option to enable it:

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

[image]

With this addition to the CKEditor configuration you should be able to see the spelling corrections underlined in your editor content.

[image]